# TeamCity NuGet feed listing package, but still can't find it

Tags: nuget, teamcity

We're stuck with a very odd problem using TeamCity as a NuGet feed. When we use Visual Studio to search for a particular package on the TeamCity feed it'll list all packages available on the feed. But then when we click one to install, it can't with the error message:

`Unable to find metadata of <package name>`

We're running out of new ideas to try, this used to work but somehow it suddenly stopped working. We haven't found any logs that point us towards something being wrong. We've tried navigating the feed `/httpAuth/app/nuget/feed/_Root/default/v3/query` which shows the package in question...

We've also tried reindexing the NuGet repo which makes the packages show up in the logs, but still they are not available...

We're using the latest version as of this moment: 2021.1 (build 92597)

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's a bug in TeamCity... we'll look into their solutions and/or update when we can https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-71659